# Java PaaS (plataform as service) for java web app (wicket - spring - hibernate/jpa - scala - jetty)

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket, paas

Which PaaS provider could I consider for deploy my app in the cloud without much pain, ie,  change structure or source code is not necessary and a provider that offers a good support for 
ides or command line too?

- Jelastic
- Cloud Bees
- OpenShift
- Heroku

Some stenches and drawbacks to evaluate for which one in the list above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/why) is the most suitable for your needs - easy to start, does not required the code changes at all, integration with Eclipse and JetBrains, different ways to deploy your app, very good performance and auto scalability.

CloudBees and Heroku have many restrictions - no public IP addresses and using A records to point external domains to apps is not supported; they do not allow to use custom ports - it means an app can only listen 80 and 443 ports; limited access to the file system - many redesign issues are related to this restriction; multicast is not supported; no vertical scaling - you should pay for the limit of virtual boxes, not for the real usage. More detailed description of benefits from the vertical scaling is here http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/truth-about-paas-vertical

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 5):

I work for OpenShift but I also think it is great for all sorts of Java support. We have Jenkins support, Tomcat 6, Tomcat 7, Jboss EAP 6, and Jboss AS 7.1. We have native data stores in MySQL, Postgresql, and MongoDB. You can use Eclipse with JBoss Developer tools for an excellent experience but we also have a command line utility and a REST API. All our building is done doing Maven so no need to change your source structure. You can also deploy war files if you want. All the PaaSs you are looking at are great so I encourage you to try a couple.

Here is a [openshift page for Java](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/java) developers. Take a look and would love some feedback

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has been well established and has even been fortunate enough to partner with Facebook. So it is well proven. There are many add-ons that you can use for your app and it is extremely easy to implement.Yet, it doesn't have PHP functionality if that is necessary

I'm sure you have looked at this: [link](http://cloud-computing.findthebest.com/saved_search/Best-PaaS-Cloud-Computing-Providers)